# My boot partition no longer shows under UEFI menu options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

(Alternate forums or tag suggestions welcome, posting here because I usually use Ubuntu desktop daily. Tags selected because they are what were auto suggested but I wasn't sure)

Today I started my laptop as usual and rather than being dropped into my Ubuntu grub menu, instead my laptop tried to start pop-os, which I installed about a month ago on a separate partition and then forgot about.

I did some googling and started my laptop in bios mode. Under boot devices, only these two are showing, there used to be several:
[image]

Here's a screen shot of my hard drive within the Disks utility UI:
[image]

Those two ubuntu partitions are what usually start when I restart my laptop. Previously, if I had wanted to boot into pop-os I would have had to press F12 at start up and then select the one containing pop-os, the one in the first screen shot above.

So it seems that without any changes I'm aware off and out of the blue, I am now no longer able to boot into ubuntu. I've been using these two partitions in the screen shot, 'ubuntu-original' and 'ubuntu-personal' for a long time with no issues like this. To switch between them I would restart my laptop, a grub gui would show allowing me to press up or down arrow to select which one I wanted and then my laptop would boot into my chosen ubuntu partition.

But the Ubuntu option no longer shows up under BIOS and instead my laptop defaults to booting into pop-os.

I'm at a loss for where to go next. I can see that my ubuntu partitions still exist from within the Disks utility (logged into pop-os just now).

Is there any other info I can provide?

How can I boot into my ubuntu partitions?

Comment: Are all installs in UEFI boot mode? They should be. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Running boot repair solved my problem. I don't know how or why but it did! Good to know about this tool.

Comment: I rarely use or need Boot-Repair, but only have Linux installs. But do like the report it creates to document my configuration. Helps me know what is where and how it is booting. Some data like details on partitions by sector could be vital to major recovery of a drive, if partitions are lost or corrupted. Run report & include it in your backups. Default report may be in /var/log/boot-repair/bootinfo....txt. I move it to /home so part of my backup as I do not normally backup /var.

Comment: @oldfred any recommended resources for learning about 'this stuff'? By that I mean boot, bios, uefi, and other concepts I really don't understand but that came up in this event? Seeking ABCs and 123s in bitesize form rather than expert knowledge.

Comment: This probably is expert knowledge. But if you go to bottom there are links to terms/acronyms which you need to understand. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295 Almost all my knowledge is from helping forum & here. Started with simple issues. Sometimes went back and looked at question that was answered and came up with my answer before looking at correct answer to see if I understood it & could then help others.